# Opening Mdi Parent as an Object won't let open Mdi Child form from another Mdi Child Form in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mdi, mdiparent

I got a weird problem with MDI Parent form. 
I open forms like -> **Login Form**(is not a MdiContainer) -> **MdiParent** (Is a MdiContainer).
But I **wanted to pass a boolean** value **from Login Form to MdiParent** Form so I **declared a Friend variable in MdiParent** Form and called MdiParent Object in Login Form as shown in below code.

```
Dim frm As New MdiParent
'frm.NormalMode = True
frm.Show()
```

Everything works fine. MDIParent form opened as expected. 
But I have some child form in MdiParent form. 
**A child Form has a button which does is open another child form with Parent MDIParent shown below.**

```
Dim frm1 As New Child2
frm1.MdiParent = MdiParent
frm1.anyvariable = value
frm1.Show()
```

But now **it won't open**. Like on button click it comes to the breakpoint passes through `frm1.show()` command line but it won't open.

Before I was Opening MDIParent directly like `MdiParent.show()` and everything worked fine. 
All child Forms opened properly with this code.

**Something Extra:** 
Also, When I run with `MdiParent.Show()`  and Pause the code in VS2017 and uncomment the MDIParent code with Object (the one above) and comment `MdiParent.Show()`  It works fine. Again, stopping and replaying the code creates issues.
Also, I didn't use that Boolean variable in MdiParent Form yet so it's not a problem I guess.
Using a Public variable is a convenient way, for now, I guess. 
Also declaring Friend variables between two child forms is not an issue at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what's happening is that, in this line:

```vb
frm1.MdiParent = MdiParent
```

the part on the right is being interpreted as being the default instance of the `MdiParent` class rather than the `MdiParent` property of the current form. As a result, the new form is being parented by that default instance, which you haven't displayed, rather than the instance that you explicitly created and did display. That would also explain why it works when you use this:

```vb
MdiParent.Show()
```

which is displaying the default instance. The fix is easy. You just need to qualify the name to indicate that it is actually the property of the current form that you're referring to:

```vb
frm1.MdiParent = Me.MdiParent
```

Alternatively, use a better name for your form than `MdiParent`, like `MainForm` or the like. Then there will be no name clash.

Comment: Thats just a typo mistake. But problem is not with that. Its just what I shown what I written in a child form to open another child form. And I changed in question.

Comment: This is not an answer @jmcilhinney

Comment: @bonny, I have edited my answer, but please copy and paste your actual code in future, so we can avoid wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Apologies for that but I think if I put actual code then it might be like not understandable and I have to explain more to them... I'll put actual code next time.

Comment: Apologies again, I actually used a different name in my project. `BonnyMdi` but again the same reason as written in the above comment.